# Applying a custom function to multiple files and creating unique csv output in R

Tags: r, function, csv

I am a beginner user in R and have been compiling a code to create a custom function to execute a specific task on some data that I possess. The custom function is structured to identify missing data in a csv file and patch this using the mean value. Thereafter, I want to summarize the data by year and month and export this as a csv file. I have multiple csv files that are sitting in a folder and would like to perform this task on each of these files. Thus far, I am able to get the code to perform the task at hand but don't know how to write a unique output for each csv file that has been processed and save these to a new folder. I would also like to retain the original file name in the processed output but have the words "_processed" appended to it. Additionally, any suggestions on how this code can be improved are most welcome. Thanks in advance.

```
# Load all packages required by the script
library(tidyverse) # data science package
library(lubridate) # work with dates
library(dplyr)     # data manipulation (filter, summarize, mutate)
library(ggplot2)   # graphics
library(gridExtra) # tile several plots next to each other
library(scales)

# Set the working directory #
setwd("H:/Shaeden_Post_Doc/Genus_Exchange/GEE_Data/MODIS_Product_Data_Raw/Cold_Temperate_Moist")


#create a function to summarize data by year and month
#patch missing values using the average

summarize_by_month = function(df){
  
# counting unique, missing and mean values in the ET column
df %>% summarise(n = n_distinct(ET),
                   na = sum(is.na(ET)),
                   med = mean(ET, na.rm = TRUE))
  
# assign mean values to the missing data and modify the dataframe
df = df %>%
    mutate(ET = replace(ET,is.na(ET),mean(ET, na.rm = TRUE)))
df
  
#separate data into year, month and day  
df$date = as.Date(df$date,format="%Y/%m/%d")

#summarize by year and month 

df %>%
    mutate(year = format(date, "%Y"), month = format(date, "%m")) %>%
    group_by(year, month) %>%
    summarise(mean_monthly = mean(ET))

}

#import all files and execute custom function for each
file_list = list.files(pattern="AET", full.names=TRUE)
file_list

my_AET_files = lapply(file_list, read_csv)
monthly_AET = lapply(my_AET_files, summarize_by_month)
monthly_AET
```

A link to the sample datasets is provided below
*https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1pLHt-vT87lxzW2We-AS1PwVcne3ALP2d?usp=sharing*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read, manipulate data and write the csv in the same function :

```
library(dplyr)

summarize_by_month = function(file) {
  df <- readr::read_csv(file)

  # assign mean values to the missing data and modify the dataframe
  df = df %>% mutate(ET = replace(ET,is.na(ET),mean(ET, na.rm = TRUE)))

  #separate data into year, month and day  
  df$date = as.Date(df$date,format="%Y/%m/%d")

  #summarize by year and month 
  new_df <- df %>%
    mutate(year = format(date, "%Y"), month = format(date, "%m")) %>%
    group_by(year, month) %>%
    summarise(mean_monthly = mean(ET))
  
     write.csv(new_df, sprintf('output_folder/%s_processed.csv', 
           tools::file_path_sans_ext(basename(file))), row.names = FALSE)
}

monthly_AET = lapply(file_list, summarize_by_month)
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, it appears to be quite a simple addition to the function and definitely something that I would like to use. I have specified the file path to the output folder which the csv files will be written to (in the code above) and then reran the code but am now receiving the following error                                                                        "Error in as.character(x) : 
  cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'character' ". What could be causing this error?

Comment: @ShaedenGokool I changed last line of the code in `write.csv` by adding `basename`. Can you run this again and check if that corrects it?

Comment: @RounakShah. I have modified my code based on your most recent suggestion, see above. The previous error no longer appears but now I receive the following error "Error: `file` must be a string, raw vector or a connection." Thanks for your assistance.

Comment: @ShaedenGokool You need to read the data inside the function and not with `lapply` outside. See my updated answer where I pass `file_list` to `summarize_by_month` function.

Comment: @RounakShah. Thanks greatly for this it worked perfectly. Kind regards.

Answer (score 0):

```
path<-"your_peferred_path/" #set a path to were you want to save the files

x<-list.files(pattern= "your_pattern") # create a list of your file names

name<-str_sub(x, start=xL, end=yL) #x & y being the part of the name you want to keep 

for (i in 1:length(monthly_AET)){
  write_excel_csv(monthly_AET[i], paste0(path, name, "_processed.csv")) # paste0 allows to create custom names from variables and static strings
}
```

note: this is only an assumption and may have to be tweaked to suit your needs